# Двухуровневый древовидный запрос

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Существуют следующие вводные

Таблица (в рабочем примере выглядит как запрос)

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  m_id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(255),
  ind NUMBER
);
```

Данные

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (m_id, name, ind)
VALUES
(1, 'John', 1),
(1, 'John', 2),
(2, 'Alice', 1),
(2, 'Alice', 2),
(3, 'Acinit', 1),
(3, 'Acinit', 3),
(3, 'Acinit', 2),
(4, 'Test', 1);
```

| M_ID | NAME | IND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 2 | Alice | 1 |
| 2 | Alice | 2 |
| 3 | Acinit | 1 |
| 3 | Acinit | 3 |
| 3 | Acinit | 2 |
| 4 | Test | 1 |

Необходимо создать такой запрос, при котором от каждого `ind` формируются группы
т.е.

| m_id | name | ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | **group1** | 1 |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 2 | Alice | 1 |
| 3 | Acinit | 1 |
| 4 | Test | 1 |
|  | **group2** | 2 |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 2 | Alice | 2 |
| 3 | Acinit | 2 |
|  | **group3** | 3 |
| 3 | Acinit | 3 |

Группы формируются внутри запроса от `dual`.

```
select
null as m_id, 'group1' as name, 1 as ind from dual
union all
select 
null as m_id, 'group2' as name, 2 as ind from dual
union all
select 
null as m_id, 'group3' as name, 3 as ind from dual
```

[P.S. Среда в db<>fiddle если кому потребуется](https://dbfiddle.uk/tHRIMGKy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если строки `group1`, `group2`... надо формировать на лету, то можно примерно так:

```
select m_id, decode(grouping(m_id), 0, name, 'group'||ind) name, ind
from your_table_name 
group by grouping sets((m_id, name, ind), ind)
order by ind, grouping(m_id) desc, m_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую попробовать этот запрос:

```
SELECT NULL AS m_id, 'group1' AS name, 1 AS ind FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT m_id, name, ind FROM your_table_name WHERE ind = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS m_id, 'group2' AS name, 2 AS ind FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT m_id, name, ind FROM your_table_name WHERE ind = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS m_id, 'group3' AS name, 3 AS ind FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT m_id, name, ind FROM your_table_name WHERE ind = 3
```

Он выведет следующий результат:

```
M_ID    NAME    IND
(null)  group1  1
1   John    1
2   Alice   1
3   Acinit  1
4   Test    1
(null)  group2  2
1   John    2
2   Alice   2
3   Acinit  2
(null)  group3  3
3   Acinit  3
```

Это тот результат, который Вы хотели бы видеть?

Comment: В принципе это решение, которое соответствует ожидаемому результату, но вот только скажем что конструкция с группами настолько огромная, что копировать её и писать столько же раз сколько юнионов - будет довольно таки болезненно